# Manipulation of unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set that can be constructed in the following way:

\begin{align}
B&=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} F_{i,j}\\
&= (F_{11} \cup F_{12} \cup \ldots \cup F_{1n})\cap(F_{21} \cup F_{22} \cup \ldots \cup F_{2n})\cap \ldots \cap(F_{k1} \cup F_{k2} \cup \ldots \cup F_{kn})
\end{align}

Where $F_{i,j}=E_{j}$ or $E_{j}^{c}$ (may be different for each $i$).

**For a proof I am doing, I want to write the above as the union of the intersections of the $F_{i,j}$'s.** Although I am not sure if this can be done, by the nature of the sets $F_{i,j}$ I believe the above union/intersection can at least be simplified.

Originally I thought (foolishly) that unions and intersections could commute, but much to my dismay, they cannot. I need some generalized version of the distributive law that will allow me to collapse this union/intersection.

Can anyone provide a generalized distributive law that might help simplify the above?

Comment: Is the choice of $E_j$ or $E_j^c$ the same for all $j$ (if $i$ is the same)? Maybe you can use this?

Comment: @skyking I am not sure if I understand, but for example $F_{11}\cup F_{12}\cup \ldots F_{1n}$ might actually be $E_{1}\cup E_{2}^{c}\cup \ldots E_{n}$ or it could be $E_{1}^{c} \cup E_{2}^{c}\cup \ldots E_{n}$ or $E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup \ldots E_{n}^{c}$ etc. etc.

Comment: Then i suppose that should say $E_j$ or $E_j^c$ (may be different for each $i$ **and** $j$)? If it were only dependent on $i$ it would be complemented or non-complemented across an entire union.

Comment: @skyking I am still not sure if I understand. If $F_{1,j}=E_{j}^{c}$ it is still possible that $F_{2,j}=E_{j}$ (i.e. it may be different for each $i$,which is why I wrote "maybe different across each $i$). However, if $F_{1,1}=E_{1}^{c}$ of course $F_{1,2}$ can equal either $E_{2}$ or $E_{2}^{c}$ (this has nothing to do with set $E_{1}$). Since by definition $F_{i,j} \neq F_{i,k}$ for $j\neq k$,variation across $j$ is implied.

Comment: I don't think that variation across $j$ is implied, especially when you only explicitely said that there's variation across $i$. That $F_{i,j} \ne F_{i,k}$ doesn't imply that - think of it, it could have been that variation across $j$ was prohibited (that's a possibility that rules out that the opposite is implied).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^k\bigcup_{j=1}^nF_{i,j}$$ if and only if for each $i\in[k]=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ there is a $j\in[n]$ such that $x\in F_{i,j}$. If ${^{[k]}[n]}$ is the set of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$, this amounts to saying that $$x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^k\bigcup_{j=1}^nF_{i,j}$$ if and only if there is a $\varphi\in{^{[k]}[n]}$ such that

$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in[k]}F_{i,\varphi(i)}\;.$$

Thus,

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^k\bigcup_{j=1}^nF_{i,j}=\bigcup_{\varphi\in{^{[k]}[n]}}\,\bigcap_{i\in[k]}F_{i,\varphi(i)}\;.$$

This distributive law holds irrespective of the specific nature of the sets $F_{i,j}$.